# Why does the ag-grid api method return more filter values than selected?

Tags: ag-grid

There is a problem in getting the right filter values selected.
I’ll make a filter in one column, then in another column, we’ll also filter ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8usve.png)

And when using the API methods - getFilterModel or getModelFromUi, then these methods return the selected values and values that are no longer visible
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYPGu.png)

but in the input field is everything that I selected, is there any way to get this value?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRJR1.png)

Comment: where do you call this getFilterModel ?

Comment: thanks, i already solved the problem

Comment: what was the issue?